# how to send multiple dropdown list value into database

Tags: php, arrays, database, dropdown

i tried to insert multiple dropdownlist value into one table in the database. But it only send the last entry. Newbies here. Need help

This is my code

```
 <tr>
    <td><select name="subjekSPM">
      <option value="bi">Bahasa Inggeris</option>
      <option value="math">Matematik</option>
      <option value="mTamb">Matematik Tambahan</option>
      <option value="tm">Teknologi Maklumat</option>
      <option value="kimia">Kimia</option>
      <option value="biologi">Biologi</option>
      <option value="akaun">Prinsip Akaun</option>
      <option value="lk">Lukisan Kejuruteraan</option>
      <option value="lukisan">Lukisan</option>
      <option value="seni">Pendidikan Seni</option>
      <option value="visual">Komunikasi Visual</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><select name="gred">
      <option value="10">A+</option>
      <option value="9">A</option>
      <option value="8">A-</option>
      <option value="7">B+</option>
      <option value="6">B</option>
      <option value="5">C+</option>
      <option value="4">C</option>
      <option value="3">D</option>
      <option value="2">E</option>
      <option value="1">F</option>
      <option value="0">G</option>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select name="subjekSPM">
      <option value="bi">Bahasa Inggeris</option>
      <option value="math">Matematik</option>
      <option value="mTamb">Matematik Tambahan</option>
      <option value="tm">Teknologi Maklumat</option>
      <option value="kimia">Kimia</option>
      <option value="biologi">Biologi</option>
      <option value="akaun">Prinsip Akaun</option>
      <option value="lk">Lukisan Kejuruteraan</option>
      <option value="lukisan">Lukisan</option>
      <option value="seni">Pendidikan Seni</option>
      <option value="visual">Komunikasi Visual</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><select name="gred">
      <option value="10">A+</option>
      <option value="9">A</option>
      <option value="8">A-</option>
      <option value="7">B+</option>
      <option value="6">B</option>
      <option value="5">C+</option>
      <option value="4">C</option>
      <option value="3">D</option>
      <option value="2">E</option>
      <option value="1">F</option>
      <option value="0">G</option>
    </select></td>
```

As i mention when i run this it only send the second entry into the database. Some suggest me to use an array. but i dont know exactly how.

Comment: We do not see your form, but when you click your submit button, you have 4 select in there.  But you gave the same name to both groups.  Call the first select subjekSPM1 and gred1, the second group subjekSPM2 and gred2.  You will now see all 4 values in your $_POST variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use this :

PHP

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['subjekSPM']))
{
foreach($_POST['subjekSPM'] as $selectedvalue)
{
    echo $selectedvalue;
}

}

?>
```

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td><select name="subjekSPM[]">
      <option value="bi">Bahasa Inggeris</option>
      <option value="math">Matematik</option>
      <option value="mTamb">Matematik Tambahan</option>
      <option value="tm">Teknologi Maklumat</option>
      <option value="kimia">Kimia</option>
      <option value="biologi">Biologi</option>
      <option value="akaun">Prinsip Akaun</option>
      <option value="lk">Lukisan Kejuruteraan</option>
      <option value="lukisan">Lukisan</option>
      <option value="seni">Pendidikan Seni</option>
      <option value="visual">Komunikasi Visual</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><select name="gred">
      <option value="10">A+</option>
      <option value="9">A</option>
      <option value="8">A-</option>
      <option value="7">B+</option>
      <option value="6">B</option>
      <option value="5">C+</option>
      <option value="4">C</option>
      <option value="3">D</option>
      <option value="2">E</option>
      <option value="1">F</option>
      <option value="0">G</option>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select name="subjekSPM[]">
      <option value="bi">Bahasa Inggeris</option>
      <option value="math">Matematik</option>
      <option value="mTamb">Matematik Tambahan</option>
      <option value="tm">Teknologi Maklumat</option>
      <option value="kimia">Kimia</option>
      <option value="biologi">Biologi</option>
      <option value="akaun">Prinsip Akaun</option>
      <option value="lk">Lukisan Kejuruteraan</option>
      <option value="lukisan">Lukisan</option>
      <option value="seni">Pendidikan Seni</option>
      <option value="visual">Komunikasi Visual</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><select name="gred">
      <option value="10">A+</option>
      <option value="9">A</option>
      <option value="8">A-</option>
      <option value="7">B+</option>
      <option value="6">B</option>
      <option value="5">C+</option>
      <option value="4">C</option>
      <option value="3">D</option>
      <option value="2">E</option>
      <option value="1">F</option>
      <option value="0">G</option>
    </select></td>
```

Comment: Explanation please?

Comment: There you save your dropdown value in array variable. SubjekSPM[] is behave like nested array for post variable. enjoy!

Comment: You have to use jquery for best control what you want

Comment: @Uday is there he tagged jquery or javascript. No na, then why we confuse the developer for the unnecessary things. maybe but itn't a point he knows the jquery. If this then you have to share your code for the same and enjoy it.

Comment: tengs brotha! this one really helps. i do get the result i want.

Comment: lovely banner effect, mind removing those? edit: oh, Jay did that for you. As per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47300025/1

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I will take it for future reference and give best explanation as I can  thanks all for your precious comments. Specially for @jay.

Comment: Awwww, I'm glad you think they're precious. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Get the values of the fields when submit button clicks

```
$_POST['subjekSPM'];
$_POST['gred'];
$_POST['subjekSPM'];
```

then you can insert in into database